# youtube video comment downloader using python

Tags: python

"youtube video comment is fetched using the json file "

```
import simplejson as json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys
import time
import csv
import os
import io
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\data science')
csvFile =open('test1.csv',"w")
#csvFile =open('test.tsv',"w")
#writer = csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter=',')
#writer.writerow('Comments')
csvFile.write("comments\n")
STAGGER_TIME = 1 

# open the url and the screen name 
# (The screen name is the screen name of the user for whom to return results for)
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=AIzaSyCYkTUjKgFGcKDnkNQMgSBbb4obnqIzUEM&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=Ye8mB6VsUHw&maxResults=100"
```

" this takes a python object and dumps it to a string which is a JSON
 representation of that object"

```
url1=urlopen(url)
#data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
result = json.load(url1)


# print the result
itemList= result.get("items")
length=len(itemList)

for i in range(0,length):
    results= (result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8")
    print(results)
    results=results.replace(",", "")
    #print (result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8")
    #writer.writerow((result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8"))
    csvFile.write(results)
    csvFile.write('\n')
    time.sleep(STAGGER_TIME)

csvFile.close()
```

"getting an error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str"

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-a5225431e178> in <module>()
     32         results= (result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8")
     33         print(results)
---> 34         results=results.replace(",", "")
     35         #print (result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8")
     36         #writer.writerow((result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8"))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: try `results.decode('utf-8').replace...`

Comment: while putting that comments into excel file its give the error                            characters in position 20-23: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

```
results= (result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")).encode("utf-8")
```

The blame here is on the last part `.encode("utf-8")` which converts the string to bytes, which is fine, except then you're trying to use `replace` using regular strings. Suggestions (whatever suits you best):

Option 1 If you can, simply remove that part from the line

```
results = result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")
```

Option 2 Add `decode` before trying to `replace`:

```
results = results.decode().replace(",", "")
```

Option 3 Use `replace` with proper bytes:

```
results = results.replace(b",", b"")
```

Option 1 is the ideal one because it's simpler, and also more compatible with the rest of the code (no need to convert to bytes in the first place, it serves no purpose I can see)

Comment: The results apparently have to be utf-8 in the end, so options 1 and 2 should have an `encode('utf-8')` after the `replace` call.

Comment: I'd that's the case, yes, or use option 3

Comment: after that it unable to write to csv file giving an error "characters in position 20-23: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: @ADITYA after option 3? If so, open another question for that

Comment: @OferSadan thanks for rply. please go through the question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800076/youtube-video-comment-downloader-in-python-3-6